# Check if the content of text area is empty (java)

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a `textarea (JTextArea)` and store the contents into a `table(MySQL)`. I don't want the `INSERT` query to execute if the textarea is empty or has a newline without any text. I tried the following code but it does not work. Could someone help me out.  Thanks.

```
String data=todo_area.getText();//read contents of text area into 'data'
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
boolean hasNewline = data.contains(newline);

if (data == null || !data.trim().equals("")||hasNewline==false)
{
    //INSERT  query
}
```

Comment: `if (data == null || data.trim().length() == 0 || !hasNewLine)` should do the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String data=todo_area.getText().trim(); //read contents of text area into 'data'
  if(!data.equals("")) {
     // code
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it's enough using this condition:

```
if ((data.trim().length() > 0) && (!hasNewline)){
    //do the insert
}
```

`data.trim().length() > 0` is enough to make sure that the input is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this condition for you check:

```
if ((data != null) && (data.trim().length() > 0 )  && (!hasNewline)){
//do the insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert TextArea to String
String change = textArea.getText();
if((change.isEmpty()){
}
```